# Cant install libnssutil3 on raspberry pi 3b+

Tags: pi-3b+, kodi, retropie

i have a Raspberry pi 3b+ running the latest version of Retropie. and i have a kodi port installed on retropie.

I also have installed a Netflix plugin but when i try to open any video of netflix i get an error message:
(translated dutch -> english) "`The following libraries required for Widevine CDM are missing from the system: libnss3.so, libnssutil3.so, libnspr4.so. Install these libraries to play this video.`"

[image: See the error message on screen here] (dutch) sorry for the mega picture bdw.

i have allready installed libnss3 and libnspr4 using an SSH session with sudo apt-get install libnss3 libnspr4. that worked. but the same way i did above does not work for libnssutil3. So how do i install that?

Ive searched everywhere but cant find an answer.

**So to clearify: I cant install libnssutil3.**

Device:
Raspberry PI 3B+ running Retropie 4.7.1 (and the Kodi port on top of it)

Please help!
Beldr

Comment: Why did you even post that picture? It has no additional value, since you already posted the error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libnss3` package provide `libnssutil3.so` and `libnss3.so` (You have already installed the required package)

`libnspr4` package provide `libnspr4.so`

`libnssutil3.so` should be under `/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnssutil3.so`